# use Drupal's authorization, from non-Drupal php application

Tags: php, drupal, authentication, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've written some educational web apps (HTML, js) for my kids. I've gotten to the point where I need to start tracking their progress individually, so the apps can focus more on what the individual still needs to learn, and spend less time repeating what they already know well.

To do that, I've created a Drupal site, with logins for each of the kids. Once they log in thru Drupal, I would like to have my app call some php pages (which I will write) that access Drupal's authentication states.

So my question is, if I'm writing php pages that query or update a database, how can these pages first ascertain whether the user is logged in to Drupal on that site, and if so, get the name of the currently authenticated user?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Note to self: see http://drupal.org/node/841036 and http://drupalbin.com/15164?nocache=1 on bootstrapping Drupal... also https://drupal.org/node/907554 and http://www.givegoodweb.com/post/95/drupal-get-username-from-uid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start your pages with this code (taken from Drupal's index.php)

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

You may need to adjust the paths if your scripts aren't in the same folder as Drupal's index.php.

Then you have full access to the Drupal API in your script, and the user's session will be loaded.  You'll need to bootstrap Drupal with this code before the suggestion above will work.  From there, you can do

```
global $user;
print_r($user);
```

Now you can do things like:

```
$other_user = user_load($some_user_id);
```

In the long run you really would get a lot of benefits from building this as a Drupal module.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. +1. Will "accept" if I can test it as working.

Comment: Right now the `print_r($user)` outputs: `stdClass Object ( [uid] => 0 [hostname] => 208.145.81.2 [roles] => Array ( [1] => anonymous user ) [cache] => 0 ) 0`, that is, anonymous user - even though I am logged in as a drupal user. I can see cookies like this in the request: auth_key=135a6d6a443b3c83dfcc42934c9b17c3; imp_key=dbcee1969a2f2bb875a2f1cc215ffe28; horde_menu_expanded=expoptions; SESS0759e2dd6117ae47acf69d8594455697=Wa6ac5va7qMl6FHhybaFGmfMcZi0Z3ldD56Fc7w_I8s But maybe it doesn't work unless the PHP scripts URL is "underneath" the Drupal site's URL?

Comment: Where is your test script relative to Drupal's index.php?  I just tried it on one of my installs, where test.php is in the same folder as index.php, and it works fine.  I see user Chris, which is the user I'm logged in as.  My site is something.localhost, and my test file is something.localhost/test.php

Comment: Thanks Chris. My test script is in a great-nephewish directory from that of index.php. I will put it in the same directory and see if that fixes the problem. I don't want to have to put my PHP scripts in a separate place from the rest of my app, but if that's what it takes...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it should work from another location in the filesystem as long as your app runs on the same host name and port.

Comment: I moved getUser.php into the same directory as index.php, and now it reports the logged-in user accurately. So ... I guess it has to be under the drupal directory hierarchy in order to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting... I tried having getUser.php in another directory but using `chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT)` before `drupal_bootstrap()`. No dice... it changed directory successfully, but `$user` still has `[uid] => 0`. Apparently the URL for getUser.php actually has to be under the Drupal URL. :-(

Comment: In that case the line define('DRUPAL_ROOT'...) is not correct.  Don't do the chdir(), but define DRUPAL_ROOT as the folder that Drupal's index.php lives in. Looking in bootstrap.php, it prefixes all of it's includes with DRUPAL_ROOT, so that should work.

Comment: That's what I did initially (my 2nd comment on this answer), and it didn't work. I'm not sure why you say the line `define('DRUPAL_ROOT'...)` is not correct. If that were the case, `require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';` would throw an error, and then `drupal_bootstrap()` wouldn't be defined... right? But instead `drupal_bootstrap()` appears to set `$user`.

Answer (score 2):

I thinks its easier to create a Drupal module from your PHP scripts. You won't have to worry about authentication then. Just my opinion.

Comment: I think that sounds promising. Can you tell me more -- point me to info on (a) how to make my scripts into a Drupal module, and (b) if my scripts were in a Drupal module, how would they determine the current authenticated user? I actually want to get "entangled" in Drupal as little as possible - I just wanted something to handle authentication and login sessions for me. But maybe this is the most straightforward way.

Comment: Well every Drupal module is basically a folder with two files. The name of your folder is the name of your module. If your module name is  say 'abc' then the files are 'abc'.info and 'abc.module'. Describe the module in your info file and write the code in your abc.module file. In the module file you should write hook_menu function (function abc_menu) which provides the exact link to your application in the Drupal way and it will appear in the sidebar. There are many tutorials regarding that on the web. Since you know PHP it wont be a problem. Drupal modules are simply PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services)

> A standardized solution of integrating external applications with
>   Drupal. Service callbacks may be used with multiple interfaces like
>   REST, XMLRPC, JSON, JSON-RPC, SOAP, AMF, etc. This allows a Drupal
>   site to provide web services via multiple interfaces while using the
>   same callback code.

**Update:**

If that's the case, you can write the code within drupal. No need for external applications.

To find out the current logged in user, use this code sample:

```
global $user;
print_r($user); // print out the user object
```

Hope this helps... Muhammad.

Comment: Muhammad, thanks for responding. The services module looks like it has potential, but so far I've been unable to find documentation or example of how PHP code could use this API to query the currently authenticated Drupal user. I'm not sure web services (in the broad sense) are appropriate here... my php pages and the Drupal site are on the same host, so presumably I could call their PHP code directly (as opposed to using HTTP). However I'm a Drupal noob so I don't know the first thing about finding how to do that.

Comment: One PHP page would say, "If there is a current logged-in Drupal user, query a database table to find that user's score and history on learning exercise X and return it in json." The part I need help with is retrieving the current authenticated Drupal user.

Comment: Are you using the same database that the drupal site uses ?!

Comment: No, I wasn't planning to. Would that make it easier or harder?

Comment: OK, let's assume I do it that way. (But my question isn't about how to access the database.) How would I then find out the current logged-in Drupal user?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Let me know if further help is needed.

Comment: Thanks. We're getting closer. You're showing me the solution "within Drupal - No need for external applications." But external apps is where I am; "within Drupal" is where I'm not. If I can put my external PHP scripts "within Drupal" in a fairly straightforward way, then I am willing to do that; please point me to how that would be done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem is here : [Drupal - using boostrap to check logged in user outside of Drupal not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357967/drupal-using-boostrap-to-check-logged-in-user-outside-of-drupal-not-working)

The bootstrap code works, you just need to set the $cookie_domain in settings.php

Answer (score 0):

this file should be inside drupal installation
**It is hell easy**

```
//set the working directory to your Drupal root
define("DRUPAL_ROOT",     "/var/www/drupal/");

//require the bootstrap include
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';

//Load Drupal
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); 
//(loads everything, but doesn't render anything)

$name = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';

//use drupal user_authenticate function
if(!user_authenticate($name, $password)){
    echo 'invalid';
}else{
    echo 'valid';
}
```